# how can I format this string as the question asks?

Tags: python

I am stumped on a homework problem. I don't need to describe it because its all explained in the image. But I have no clue where to start I'm new to Python and I'm on a time limit so this is my only option, thanks guys.[image]

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried yet ?

Comment: does the `mult_table` parts is yours or theirs ,do we need to use them

Comment: The solution has to come after the block comment below, so everything above that line is provided. This is also obvious, since the OP is unable to write a nested loop by himself, so it is safe to assume he cannot formulate a nested list comprehension, either. Also see the comment above the list comprehension, this makes it even more obvious.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa here nested loops are just hint.  That's not mandatory to mention.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this,

```
user_input = input()
lines = user_input.split(',')

multi_table = [[ int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]

for l1 in multi_table:
    line = ""
    for l2 in l1:
        line += f" {l2} |"
    print(line[:-1].strip())
```

And output will be:

```
1 | 2 | 3
2 | 4 | 6
3 | 6 | 9
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: It almost worked, they only problem is there is an extra white space before and after each row

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
for line in lines:
 print(re.sub(' ',' | ',line))
```

**or**

In your case:

```
for l in mult_table:
  for i,x in enumerate(l):
    if i != len(l)-1:
      print(x,end=' | ')
    else:
      print(x,end=' ')

  print('')
```

Comment: While this prints the correct result, this is not using nested loops (explicitly), so it does not answer the question. And it is not using the provided mult_table.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa modified the answer

Comment: This answer almost worked except there is an extra whitespace after each row

Comment: @Alfred remove the spaces in `print(x,end='|')` and try

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = input()
lines = user_input.split(',')

multi_table = [[ int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]
for j in multi_table:
    print(str(j).replace(',', ' |').replace('[',' ').replace(']',' '))
```

> 1 | 2 | 3
>   4 | 5 | 6
>   7 | 8 | 9

Comment: This does not print the `' | '` separators. And it is not using the provided `mult_table`.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa by mistake,  now its modified.

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
text=input()
line=text.split(',')
for i in line:
    print(' | '.join(i.split(' ')))
```

Summary code:

```
for i in input().split(','):
    print(' | '.join(i.split(' ')))
```

Output:

```
1 | 2 | 3
2 | 4 | 6
3 | 6 | 9
```

Comment: While this prints the correct result, this is not using nested loops (explicitly), so it does not answer the question. And it is not using the provided `mult_table`.